# Assembly mkdir in linux os

Tags: linux, function, assembly, operating-system

I should create in assembly code (at & t Style) a function that creates a directory (Linux OS).debugging with gdb when I run my code returns a permission error. I think I'm wrong in passing parameters.
thank you very much.

```
 .data
 Messaggio:   .string   "Salve\n"
 cartella:    .string   "prova" 
 length = .-Messaggio
s_irusr  =    00400
s_iwusr  =    00200
s_ixusr  =    00100
.text

.global _lpshow
.global _cd

_lpshow:

    mov $4,%eax        
    mov $1,%ebx       #stdout
    mov $Messaggio,%ecx    #message address
    mov $length,%edx        # message string length
    int $0x80

    #sys_exit(return_code)

    mov $1,%eax        # sys_exit syscall
    mov $0,%ebx        #return 0 (success)
    int $0x80
ret 

_cd :
    mov $39,%eax
    mov $cartella,%ebx
    mov s_iwusr|s_irusr|s_ixusr,%ecx
    int $0x80
ret
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message you are receiving and also the command prompt output when you execute your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `mov s_iwusr|s_irusr|s_ixusr,%ecx` is missing a `$` sign to denote an immediate, like `mov $s_iwusr|s_irusr|s_ixusr,%ecx`.

Of course the code as-is will exit before it even tries to create the directory, but I assume you have something that tries to `call _cd` (which is a misleading name, by the way).

Comment: you're right, in italy cd (the initials of the crea directory = English make directory)   thanks, I try to change the line

Comment: Create directory is fine in english too, but the point is that `cd` usually means `change directory`.

Comment: I tried it and I get this error   __libc_start_main (main=0x80483ed <main>, argc=1, ubp_av=0xbffff6c4, 
    init=0x8048430 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=0x80484a0 <__libc_csu_fini>, 
    rtld_fini=0xb7fed5f0 <_dl_fini>, stack_end=0xbffff6bc) at libc-start.c:294
294 libc-start.c: File o directory non esistente.

Comment: I solved it, the folder had the same name of the program  cartella:    .string   "prova1"